# Mosaic plot not showing labels

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

probably this will interest you.

I'm running a mosaic plot in R, but I am not able to get de rows label names (just the columns).

This is the code:

```
xy=table(data$X, data$Y)
mosaicplot (xy, color=2:3, las=2)
```

Could you tell how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: There is a [nice `ggplot2` solution here](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/).

Comment: Please make a reproducible example...